# Making a pdf out of timestamps as heading and transcript as content

Tags: python, youtube, timestamp, yt-dlp

Ok so I have recently started liking long form content on YouTube and would like to achieve the following:

1. Use timestamp titles as chapter titles
2. Use transcript content as chapter content
3. Restrict transcript content within a chapter to the timestamp durations.

So if the time stamp says 0:00-04:20 Topic 1, I want the text to read Topic 1 and then the transcript content spanning from 0:00-04:20 to populate under this heading.

YouTube already has a chapter feature and its Show Transcript option that already do what I am asking here.

The problem lies here:

1. When I copy paste the text from show transcript window, it gets pasted to an editor (Notepad, Wordpad, Word etc) in plain text with no regard to the chapter headings. For a 10-20 min video it's okay. For a 3-4 hour long video, it's very difficult to skim through 40-50 pages of text, cross reference with the YouTube chapters, find and edit topics...you get what I am talking about.
2. It's cumbersome to manually repeat the process for a playlist(s) having more than a bunch of videos.

I would like to preserve timestamps within the transcribed text because:

> I intend to extract the audio from the playlist videos to play like an "audiobook"

> Use the text as a pdf to highlight and take notes away from the computer on my tablet.

> The timestamps in the text/pdf will help me return to the "audiobook" if I am to leave my study session midway.

Q: Is there a way to achieve this? To automate and output a text file or pdf for each video in a playlist? Or am I missing something here?

Tried yt-dlp but can't seem to find the exact string of commands to achieve this. Tried GPT with chrome extensions. No dough.